# How do I stop my integrated gameserver/webserver from flooding itself?

Tags: mysql

I helped make a game server for something and its an integrated webserver, it worked fine until one day when I restarted my VPS the console is flooded by my own VPS flooding the server by repeatedly connecting to the server.

What is happening
[image: Does happen]

What should happen when someone connects
[image: Does happen]

*Other info*
I run Xamp-control panel to host a mysql server

Comment: we can't help you a whole lot without seeing sourcecode